# Why does Google allow non-HTTPS searches?

Tags: tls, google

I found today that Google allows you to reach its search engine and submit searches over non-https connection.

Visiting `http://google.com`, results in a redirect to the URL `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl`

Attempting to visit `http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl` (note, the protocol) results in access to Google over non-HTTPS connection.

Why does Google allow this?

Comment: It seems that they do it in order to allow proxy's to keep up with the traffic in school environments, see [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/1l2KMUfgyo4)

Comment: What would be the reason to not allow it?

Comment: If they can't decrypt the students' Google traffic, safe-search can't be enforced.

Comment: Clearly the best way to find out why Google does something is to ask someone else.